# Images beside images with css

Tags: css

I have three images, the firsts are the brazilian flag and the english flag (language settings).. and the third  is the logo of my site...

code:

```
            <a class="language" href=""><img  src="assets/images/language/portuguese.png">Português</a>
            <a class="language" href=""><img  src="assets/images/language/english.png">English</a>
            <img class="logo" src="assets/images/logo.png">
```

I want the first and the second above the third..

So, in my css i made:

```
.language {
    margin: 0 5px 0 10px;
}

.logo {
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

There is something wrong?? it's not working.

Comment: Put </br> between the seccond and the third line

Comment: @VincentBeltman That's a horrible suggestion. Break tags should never be used for spacing...that's what margins & padding are for.

Comment: @Paulie_D What are `<br>` for then?

Comment: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/br - it creates a line break within a block of text

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you have all three images in the same "row". You didn't separate them in two rows in any way.

I would suggest putting language icons in their own div tag like this:

```
<div>
    <a class="language" href=""><img  src="assets/images/languag/portuguese.png">Português</a>
    <a class="language" href=""><img  src="assets/images/language/english.png">English</a>
</div>
    <img class="logo" src="assets/images/logo.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

More information missing from your question, but I guess that's it

```
<style type="text/css">
    .classe1 {
        background-image: url('../../Content/images/carousel2.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height:100px;
    }
</style>

<div class="classe1">
    <img src="../../Content/images/Icon1.png" alt="" width="40px" />
    <img src="../../Content/images/Icon2.png" alt="" width="40px" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make it like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapit">
    <a class="language" href=""><img src="assets/images/language/portuguese.png">Português</a>
    <a class="language" href=""><img src="assets/images/language/english.png">English</a>
    <img class="logo" src="assets/images/logo.png">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapit { 
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}
.wrapit img { width: 100%; float: left; }
.wrapit a { float: left; width: 50%; display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't influence the HTML, you can make `<br>` with CSS:

```
a + a:after {
    content: "\A";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Since `::before` and `::after` don't work on self closing tags like `<img>`, you'll have to add it to the second `<a>`

[Voila demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/22aoajbz/)